# Non-identical behaviour of symmetric armature

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I did foot controls armature on the left foot and symmetrized it for the right (btw I did the same manually without symmetrizing them and the problem appeared as well). As you can see , on the picture below when I rotate footRollCtrl.L up foot goes up and the toe stays parallel to plane. If I do the same with footRollCtrl.R the right toe moves together with the rest of the foot.
Here's the link of my project uploaded to Google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lfQUZVkqnnkMpt_DeWPyuIr1jcwICEA6/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here isn't the rig. As you can see, the rig behaves the same on both sides:

[image: comparison]

What is different is how the mesh is deformed.

If you go in Weight Paint mode, you will see that the toe area is assigned at full weight bot to your toe group and foot root:

[image: weights]

The solution is to remove the toe part from the foot weights.

Since you have it selected in Edit mode, just go in edit mode, select the foot vertex group and click remove, so that the toes vertex get unassigned from the foot.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me!